# How do you work out the order of large integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

$\Bbb Z/420$. $143 [420]$. I do not know how you would go about working the order of this? I have already worked out $\phi(420)$ to equal $96$, so I know this means there are 96 units.

Comment: Just as a small point. 420 is not a large integer by pretty much any measure. Since it is a very small integer you could actually just go ahead and perform the multiplication on 143, but to make it easier notice that once you know the size of the multiplicative group the order of the element (assuming it's part of the multiplicative group) must divide it. That very much restricts the numbers you have to try to find the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Use Carmichael Function $\lambda(420)=\cdots=12$

So for any integer $a, (a,420)=1;$   $$a^{12}\equiv1\pmod{420}\ \ \ \ (1)\implies\text{ord}_{420}a\mid12$$

Now $420=3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot4;$

$143\equiv3\pmod7\implies143^3\equiv3^3\equiv-1\pmod7$

$\implies$ord$_73=6\implies$ord$_{420}143$ will be multiple of $6$

Similarly, ord$_5143=4\implies$ord$_{420}143$ will be multiple of $4$

$\implies$ord$_{420}143$ will be multiple of lcm$(4,6)=12$

Can you use $(1)$ now?

Answer (score 0):

If $n,k\in\Bbb Z^+$, $a^{k}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ and $p\mid k\implies a^{k/p}\not\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, then $\text{ord}_n(a)=k$.

In this case, it's enough to prove $143^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{420}$ and $143^{12/2}\not\equiv 1\pmod{420}$ and $143^{12/3}\not\equiv 1\pmod{420}$.

$420=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$. It's enough to prove $143^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{2^2,3,5,7}$ and $143^{12/2}\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ and $143^{12/3}\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.